# Preference shares vs. common shares and overall holding structure for a public company?

Tags: stocks, debt, accounting, stock-valuation, preferred-stocks

I am trying to understand the overall holding picture for a listed company — like, there can be preference shares, common shares (free float), etc.

My questions are:

1. It would be really great if someone could divide and show all these as % (out of 100) ... What are the various possibilities like preference, common, etc.?
2. Are all the ratios and numbers in the balance sheet and income statement based only on free float share (like EPS, PE, etc.), *or*, are there some numbers which include the non free-float shares as well?
3. Where does debt taken on by the company fit in the overall picture?

Comment: Debt shows up on the balance sheets and affects stock price via buyers' opinions of how it affects the company.  Shares of all types together add to 100% ownership of the company.

Comment: 1.)Common shares and free float are not the same thing. Free float is the total number of shares available for trading and this usually does not include promoter shares, locked in shares and government shares. So, preference shares = shares outstanding - common shares.